# Service bound to ipv6 on linux machine - Can I disable IPV6 and access service on my IPV4 address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ipv6, ipv4

I am attempting to install Tableau Server on Ubuntu 18.04 and have the management service running on port 8850. I am unable to access the service at that port on my IPV4 address as it seems to be on my IPV6 address.

These are my listening ports:

```
systemd-r   898        systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4   14795      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)                                                                                       
sshd       1825                   root    3u  IPv4   29682      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)                                                                                                
sshd       1825                   root    4u  IPv6   29684      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)                                                                                                
appzookee  2824                tableau  242u  IPv6   25299      0t0  TCP *:8707 (LISTEN)                                                                                              
appzookee  2824                tableau  247u  IPv6   31376      0t0  TCP *:8715 (LISTEN)                                                                                              
appzookee  2824                tableau  248u  IPv6   39195      0t0  TCP *:8843 (LISTEN)                                                                                              
lmgrd      3202                tableau    0u  IPv6   35120      0t0  TCP *:27000 (LISTEN)                                                                                             
clientfil  3292                tableau  252u  IPv6   54347      0t0  TCP *:8844 (LISTEN)                                                                                              
clientfil  3292                tableau  253u  IPv6   52374      0t0  TCP *:8235 (LISTEN)                                                                                              
activatio  3354                tableau  341u  IPv6   51249      0t0  TCP *:8645 (LISTEN)                                                                                              
tabadminc  3674                tableau  413u  IPv6   62007      0t0  TCP *:8850 (LISTEN)                                                                                              
tabadmina  3866                tableau  389u  IPv6   45962      0t0  TCP *:8438 (LISTEN)                                                                                              
tabadmina  3866                tableau  394u  IPv6   58312      0t0  TCP *:8206 (LISTEN)
```

Is it possible to disable IPV6 and access that service on my IPV4 address? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disabling IPv6 will bring more problems, and is not likely to fix this.

Check a kernel tunable:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only
```

If 0, the default, Linux allows binding to both address families at once. IPv4 works as before, but is tracked by the network stack as IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses. Transparent to users, but confusing when looking at sockets with `ss`.

Try packet capture on both server and client, while attempting to connect. If packets exit the client and mysteriously never appear at the server, check all firewalls in between.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling IPv6 will not help.
You need to fix the configuration of your Tableau Server to listen on IPv4.
As you can see from the two `ssh` lines in your list, it is perfectly possible for a service to listen on a port for both IPv4 and IPv6 at the same time.